# How we can figure out some condition in .onChange of a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I what control a condition in `.onChange` of a Text, if that condition passed then I want run some codes, this is my codes, It does kind of working but it does not support my given condition, it works for true as well for false. I want it works only for true. how I can code it?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var truePhase: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(truePhase ? "Phase is True" : "Phase is False")
            .onChange(of: truePhase == true , perform: { value in
                print(truePhase)
            })
 
        Button(action: {
            truePhase.toggle()
        }){
            Text("Change Phase")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onChange` is called whenever some `Equatable` changes. If you pass a condition as the `value` parameter, the `perform` closure will be executed whenever this condition changes (regardless of it being true or false). You need to put checks inside the `perform` closure.

For this you can use e.g. a `guard` statement. Try the following:

```
.onChange(of: truePhase) { value in
    guard value else { return } // if `value` is not `true` then return
    print(truePhase) // here value is `true`
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know how I can use guard or If, I wanted the controlling part inside of () in .onChange, like my code

Comment: @Omid It's just not possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for update, I wanted more efficient coding than using (guard or if),So let me ask my question in this way, how we can put an observer for Text value change? In other words how we can observe and get notified wether the Value of Text is changed?

Comment: @Omid For Text you usually use some `@State var text = ""` variable. You can just observe it `.onChange(of: text) { value in }`

Comment: I know all about State and .onChange, and those are logical ways to observe you are right, I like to put some kind of custom notification for this view, remember my last question you put a notification at .onReceive for finding the orientation! If you think I should make another question and this are not related to this question let me know please.

Comment: @Omid It depends on where do you plan to you this value, ie. why do you need a notification instead of onReceive or onChange. So yes, best would be to create new question and describe why and where do you need to access this value.